# How does Google+ Sign-In Compare to googleappengine.api.user signin?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-plus

The "user" submodule in Google App Engine uses "Google Account" rather than a "G+" sign-in. Are the base ID's the same? I'd like to associate their sign-ins with my own user records...

Comment: Can you add some additional context here? Which API calls are you making? Are you using OAuth 2.0/OpenID/etc. on App Engine? Which language are you working in?

Comment: In python one can call google.appengine.api.user.get_current_user() which goes to Google Account (e.g. here is a sample built from a Codenvy template: http://bjorke-gap1.appspot.com ) -- this goes to "Google Accounts" login. What I'd like to know is how the values in the returned object relate to the items returned by the G+ sign-in. Is the G+ id_token always the same value as a Google Accounts ID, or are they disconnected?

Comment: Wow, crickets.... I'm using G+ signin, and also not user the app engine datastore "user" Property because of this confusion (should I use it, or just keep the various oauth2-related credentials like user ID and name as separate properties?)

Comment: Users service and oath are different services. Though users service can support federated login and open id which is deprecated slowly. Did you figure it out?

Comment: To tell the truth, I just went with G+ and ignored the "user" service since it had that deprecated sort of feel...

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking the about the ids...

Specifically:

using

`user = users.get_current_user()`

returns a user object and that is not what you are referring (regarding to your comment)

The `user_id()` is what you where reffereing to for the users api:

```
user = users.get_current_user()
user.user_id()
```

From the [Docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/userclass#User_user_id)

```
If the email address is associated with a Google account, user_id returns the unique permanent ID of the user, a str. This ID is always the same for the user regardless of whether the user changes her email address.

If the email address is not associated with a Google account, user_id returns None.
```

Now from my experience my GoogleID according to `user_id()` is `xxx8005350796570706xx` and my Google Plus profile ID is `102445631084043565507` which are totally different. I also checked this with my apps and Google + known followers and found no similarity.

Answer (score 1):

I would say they are not the same thing, but yes, you can associate them.

If you have used the support built into GAE (or Android) for basic Google accounts (User) to authenticate a user then you have their e-mail address which uniquely identifies their google account.

On Google+, use the email scope to gain access to their e-mail address:
https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#email-scopes

These e-mail addresses should match, so this will allow you to associate the Google and Google+ accounts.  The downside to this method IMO is if you weren't already requesting the g+ email scope then you will have to add it.

Comment: not true that the email is a unique identifier that cant change. It CAN change in Google-apps (not gmail) scenarios. You shoud use the unique identifier and not the email if you want to cover those cases.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an own user model which will have info about registered users. Using users.get_current_user() you may take an e-mail address from user google account and login him to an app.